# How to customize associative array data in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on laravel ACL In, my ACL system every Role have list of array permissions,My problem is when I select more than one role for a user the role permissions show me like this. I want to customize array data this format to.

`{
"read": "1",
"create": "1",
"update": "1",
"delete": "1",
"read-product": "1",
"create-product": "1",
"update-product": "1"
}`

To, This Format .

`"User":{
"read": "1",
"create": "1",
"update": "1",
"delete": "1",
}
"Admin": {
"read-product": "1",
"create-product": "1",
"update-product": "1"
"delete-product": "1"
},`

Here, Is my Controller Part.

```
 public function assignrole(Request $request)
{

    $a;

   if(is_array($request['role']))
    {
        foreach($request['role'] as $role)
        {
            $role_info=Role::find(1);
            foreach($request->permissions as $permission=>$value)
            {
                $a[$permission] = $value;
            }
        }
        return $role_info;
    }

}
```

Comment: Not sure if I am the only one who doesn't really get your intention, but please clearify what you are doing / what you need this transformation for.

Comment: i just assign more than one role to a user with lists of permissions. but when i assign role its show the all permissions. not show only given role permissions.

Comment: How does your table structure look like? And did you check whether the roles and permissions are stored in the database in the correct way?

Comment: I have an `users` and `roles` table and a pivot table `user_role` I want store permissions per user in pivot table.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. What do you have roles for in the first place if you give each user his permissions individually anyway? What you'd want is a table `permissions`, where you store the permissions for each role and `user_role` is only a pivot table to determine which user has which role.

Answer (score 0):

You should process and merge the permissions together using array_merge or array_map.

However, my suggestion would be to use a proper ACL package... i see you are using laravel, there are a few good ones on https://packagist.org/. They all come with documentation and once you set them up you don't need to bother with problems like this and go on with your app :-)

Good luck!